# Data not getting inserted to db - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I m try to insert data to db ! but function is working ok, it redirect to route assigned ! no error! but data is not getting added in db! I am not able to figure out ! anyhelp?

```
 public function addfav($webmasterId,$id)
    {
        // Check Permissions
        $data_sections_arr = explode(",", Auth::user()->permissionsGroup->data_sections);
        if (Auth::user()->id =='1') {
            return Redirect::to(route('NoPermission'))->send();
        }

        $dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId([
    ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id]
]);

        //
        // General for all pages
        $GeneralWebmasterSections = WebmasterSection::where('status', '=', '1')->orderby('row_no', 'asc')->get();
        // General END

        //Webmaster Topic Details
        $WebmasterSection = WebmasterSection::find($webmasterId);
        if (!empty($WebmasterSection)) {



            return redirect()->route('fav',['webmasterId'=>$webmasterId]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('NotFound');
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId([ ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id] ]);` change to this `$dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id]);` because you are having two `[]` so remove one

Comment: nothing happened! no error ! but still data is not getting inserted!

Comment: check your model "$fillable" array have the correct structure.

Comment: @VaibhavSinghal With `DB::table` or insert you don't need to check the model properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Why are you having two `[]` ? Remove one of them, I think this is the problem**

Change

```
$dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId([
  ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id]
]);
```

To

```
$dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId(
  ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id]
);
```

Check with try and catch, what error are you receiving

```
try{
    $dlt=DB::table('favads')->insertGetId(
      ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'topic_id' => $id]
    );

    dd($dlt);
}catch(\Exception $e){
  dd($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: still nothing !!

Comment: To which route you are actually redirect back ?

Comment: domain.co/14/addfav/21
----- 14 is webmasterid 21 is postiid

Comment: m redirect it to domain.co/14/fav

Comment: how many fields do you have in your `favads` table ?

Comment: id, topic_id, user_id

id is autoincrement!

Comment: It's impossible if you are not receiving any error, have you used try catch code correctly with `dd()` ? Also check at the top `dd($id)` whether it's null or not.

Comment: No with `dd();` it will stop the execution and show you result on the screen.

Comment: no error coming ! i m telling you! no error! coming! but still data is not getting inserted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216191/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-aryabh).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
$dlt = new Favad();
$dlt->user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
$dlt->topic_id = $id;
$dlt->save();
```

Comment: What error shows ?? In your controller use this `use App\Favad;`

Comment: yep! but still no error! also its     ***Favads***  not **Favad**

Comment: What is your `model` name??

Comment: Favads 

i already changed it in your code! but still nothing!

Comment: @Aryabh Table name is plural and Model name is singular. So it should be Favad.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are using the following code `use App\Favad;` in your controller.

You should insert data the following way:

```
$dlt = new Favad;

$dlt->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

$dlt->topic_id = $id;

$dlt->save();
```